# Rust borrowing issue with a getter method on a struct

Tags: memory-management, struct, rust, borrowing

I am new to Rust, so am still trying to get used to the memory model of the language.

So I am running into an error `cannot move out of borrowed content.` when I build a `getter` method on a struct. I could not quite figure out why it is, but it seems to relate to some trait on an Enum.

```
enum Gender{
    Male,
    Female,
}
impl Default for Gender {
    fn default() -> Gender { Gender::Female }
}
impl Clone for Gender {
    fn clone(&self) -> Gender { *self }
}


#[derive(Default, Builder, Debug)]
#[builder(setter(into))]
struct ProfessorGroup {
    name: &'static str,
    gender:Gender,
    level:Levels,
    attrition_rate:f64,
    promotion_rate:f64,
    hiring_rate:f64,
    current_number:u32,
}
impl ProfessorGroup {
    pub fn get_gender(&self) -> Gender { self.gender }
    pub fn get_name(&self) -> &'static str {self.name}
    pub fn get_attrition_rate(&self) -> f64 {self.attrition_rate}
```

The error message I am getting has to do with the `Enum` for Gender.

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
  --> src/Actors/ProfessorGroups.rs:42:33

42 |     pub fn get_gender(&self) -> Gender { self.gender }
   |                                          ^^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content

error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
  --> src/Actors/ProfessorGroups.rs:27:33
   |
27 |     fn clone(&self) -> Levels { *self }
   |                                 ^^^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content
```

I made sure to take a reference to self. I also did not make any assignment in these functions--just getter functions--yet somehow the borrowing is getting messed up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thr problem you encounter is that neither `Gender` nor `ProfessorGroup` are `Copy`.

Simply adding `#[derive(Clone, Copy)]` to both of them would solve your issues.

---

By default Rust types are *affine*. This is a strict departure from other languages, so it takes some getting used to.

An *Affine* type is a type that can be consumed (moved) at most once: think of it as a cake, you can't have your cake and eat it too right? A cake is affine!

When you write `fn get_gender(&self) -> Gender { self.gender }` you are trying to return `self.gender`: this requires moving it out of `self` which is not allowed because `self` is not yours it's only borrowed! (You can't steal someone else cake, just look at it)

There are multiple solutions:

- you can return a *reference* instead: `-> &Gender { &self.gender }`,
- you can `clone` the gender (if it implements `Clone`): `{ self.gender.clone() }`,
- you can have `Gender` implement `Copy`.

Personally, when types *can* implement `Copy`, I would recommend they do. Makes life simpler.

Comment: Ah this makes sense. I get why the getter function was still considered borrowing. Thanks for the tip on the Copy, Clone traits too. That is such a useful tip, as it seems the equivalent of passing/returning by value instead of by reference. I appreciate the clear explanation of the memory model in Rust as well.